# Create element with children inside using appendChild()

Tags: javascript, html, dom, children

I am trying to create a grid layout, where by pressing the button "NEW TARGET", a new target is created besides it. The target is everything in the lightgrey box, both the red boxes and the text saying layout: x by x. The problem I am having is that I don't know how to create a new target with all the children inside.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is the title of the webpage!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Gasflasker udvidet.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="target-wrapper" class="target-wrapper">
        <div class="target">
            <p class="archive-title">Layout: 
            <select>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
            </select>
            by
            <select>
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
            </select>
            </p>
        <div class="image" draggable="true">1</div>
        <div class="image" draggable="true">2</div>
        <div class="image" draggable="true">3</div>
        <div class="image" draggable="true">4</div>
        <div class="image" draggable="true">5</div>
        <div class="image" draggable="true">6</div>
        <div class="image" draggable="true">7</div>
        <div class="image" draggable="true">8</div>
        <div class="image" draggable="true">9</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <button id="button" class="button" onclick="newTarget()">NEW TARGET</button>
  </body>
</html>
<script src="./Gasflasker udvidet.js"></script>
```

```
.target-wrapper {
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    width: fit-content;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

.target {
    background-color:lightgrey;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    width:fit-content;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.archive-title {
    grid-column: 1/4;
}

.image {
    background-color: coral;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.button {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```
function newTarget() {
const targetWrapper = document.getElementById("target-wrapper");

const target = document.createElement("div");
target.classList.add("target");
targetWrapper.appendChild(target);
};
```

I tried using appendChild(), but that only lets me create the grey box itself, not it's children as well (at least as far as I know).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you tried just using `cloneNode` instead of creating the element?

Comment: @ChrisG No, I haven't. Does it clone the children as well?

Comment: it does, allow me to add an answer to demostrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a div to hold the original, you can use the template tag. Then simply use importNode on document to import the template's content.

```js
const addTarget = document.querySelector(".addTarget");
const target = document.querySelector("#target");
const targetWrapper = document.querySelector("#target-wrapper");

addTarget.addEventListener("click",() => {
  targetWrapper.appendChild(document.importNode(target.content, true));
});
```

```css
.target-wrapper {
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    width: fit-content;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
}

.target {
    background-color:lightgrey;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    width:fit-content;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.archive-title {
    grid-column: 1/4;
}

.image {
    background-color: coral;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.addTarget{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<template id="target">
  <div class="target">
    <p class="archive-title">Layout:
      <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
      by
      <select>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <div class="image" draggable="true">1</div>
    <div class="image" draggable="true">2</div>
    <div class="image" draggable="true">3</div>
    <div class="image" draggable="true">4</div>
    <div class="image" draggable="true">5</div>
    <div class="image" draggable="true">6</div>
    <div class="image" draggable="true">7</div>
    <div class="image" draggable="true">8</div>
    <div class="image" draggable="true">9</div>
  </div>
</template>
<div id="target-wrapper" class="target-wrapper">

</div>

  <button id="button" class="addTarget"> NEW TARGET
    </button>
```

Comment: and is there a way to id the different targets, so you can access them individually?

Comment: I need to adjust the size of the individual grids with the dropdrowns. I have gotten this to work for the first target. Do functions carry over, when you use a template?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method to clone the element along with its children and then append it like you were doing

**Note:** the only issue with this is that it will also clone the id from your element, leading to having multiple elements with the same id in some cases. This won't be a problem for you tho, since we are cloning a div with no id, it has a class `target`, so no issues there. But if you ever run into that you can just change the id of the cloned element. for example:

```
let cloneElement = div.cloneNode(true);//clone the element
cloneElement.id = 'another-id';//give it a new id
```

Full code

```js
const targetWrapper = document.getElementById("target-wrapper");

function newTarget() {
  const div = document.querySelector(".target");
  let cloneElement = div.cloneNode(true);
  targetWrapper.appendChild(cloneElement);
};
```

```css
.target-wrapper {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.target {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: fit-content;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.archive-title {
  grid-column: 1/4;
}

.image {
  background-color: coral;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>This is the title of the webpage!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Gasflasker udvidet.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="target-wrapper" class="target-wrapper">
    <div class="target">
      <p class="archive-title">Layout:
        <select>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
        by
        <select>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
        </select>
      </p>
      <div class="image" draggable="true">1</div>
      <div class="image" draggable="true">2</div>
      <div class="image" draggable="true">3</div>
      <div class="image" draggable="true">4</div>
      <div class="image" draggable="true">5</div>
      <div class="image" draggable="true">6</div>
      <div class="image" draggable="true">7</div>
      <div class="image" draggable="true">8</div>
      <div class="image" draggable="true">9</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="button" class="button" onclick="newTarget()">NEW TARGET</button>
</body>

</html>
<script src="./Gasflasker udvidet.js"></script>
```

Comment: PS: Avoid the use of inline HTML on* handlers attributes

Answer (score 1):

Copy the `target` element, including its children with [`.cloneNode(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) method, and add it to the `targetWrapper` element:

```
  const cloneTarget = document.querySelector(".target").cloneNode(true);
  document.querySelector("#target-wrapper").appendChild(cloneTarget);
```

***DEMO:***

```js
function newTarget() {
  const targetWrapper = document.querySelector("#target-wrapper");
  const target = document.querySelector(".target");
  const cloneTarget = target.cloneNode(true);
  targetWrapper.appendChild(cloneTarget);
};
```

```css
.target-wrapper {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  width: fit-content;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.target {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: fit-content;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.archive-title {
  grid-column: 1/4;
}

.image {
  background-color: coral;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="target-wrapper" class="target-wrapper">
  <div class="target">
    <div class="image" draggable="true">1</div>
    <div class="image" draggable="true">2</div>
    <div class="image" draggable="true">3</div>
    <div class="image" draggable="true">4</div>
    <div class="image" draggable="true">5</div>
    <div class="image" draggable="true">6</div>
    <div class="image" draggable="true">7</div>
    <div class="image" draggable="true">8</div>
    <div class="image" draggable="true">9</div>
  </div>

</div>
<button id="button" class="button" onclick="newTarget()">NEW TARGET</button>
```

Comment: addEventListener should be used instead of inline HTML on* attribute handlers.

Comment: addEventListener should be used instead of inline HTML on* attribute handlers.

Comment: I know it would be good if seperate code HTML from JS, but my focus was to suggest a solution to solve his problem.

Comment: Absolutely. It was more like a notice for any future reader.